# Extract properties from deleted/duplicated objects then assign to other objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I need a little help here, y have this array:

```
[
   {Code:13938, Country:699, Name:"Crocs", codeProduct:1}
   {Code:13952, Country:699, Name:"Polo Club", codeProduct:14}
   {Code:13952, Country:699, Name:"Polo Club", codeProduct:1}
   {Code:13952, Country:699, Name:"Polo Club", codeProduct:3}
   {Code:13953, Country:699, Name:"OZ", codeProduct:12}
   ....
]
```

And I need to convert to this:

```
[
   {Code:13938, Country:699, Name:"Crocs", codeProduct:1}
   {Code:13952, Country:699, Name:"Polo Club", codeProduct:"14, 1, 3" }
   {Code:13953, Country:699, Name:"Polo Club", codeProduct:12}
]
```

I have no problem removing the duplicate objects, and getting the values of those delted objects.

```
var prodArray = [];

function uniq_fast(a) {
   var seen = {};
   var out = [];
   var len = a.length;
   var j = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     var item = a[i].Codigo;
     if(seen[item] !== 1) {
           seen[item] = 1;
           out[j++] = a[i];
     }else{
        prodArray.push({Code:item, codeProduct:a[i].TipoProductoCodigo});
     }
   }
      return out;
   }
```

this return a new array of objects whitout the repited values and add to a new array `prodArray` the properties of deleted ones.

```
// out return this:
[
  {Code:13938, Country:699, Name:"Crocs", codeProduct:1}
  {Code:13952, Country:699, Name:"Polo Club", codeProduct:"14, 1, 3" }
  {Code:13953, Country:699, Name:"Polo Club", codeProduct:12}
```

]

and `prodArr` return this:

```
[
    {Code:13952, codeProduct:1}
    {Code:13952, codeProduct:3}
]
```

But how do i set the properties in `prodArray` in to the new one array that holds the no duplicate objects?.

Hope i have been clear

Comment: seems pretty inconsistent... you'd have a property that may contain either a string list or a single number.

Comment: Soooo you moved the duplicates to prodArray, and you want to add them back?

Comment: I don't understand your final question

Comment: The duplicates are returned in `uniq_fast` function, and some values of the deleted objects are en `prodArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table as reference to the `Code`.

```js
var data = [{ Code: 13938, Country: 699, Name: "Crocs", codeProduct: 1 },  { Code: 13952, Country: 699, Name: "Polo Club", codeProduct: 14 }, { Code: 13952, Country: 699, Name: "Polo Club", codeProduct: 1 }, { Code: 13952, Country: 699, Name: "Polo Club", codeProduct: 3 }, { Code: 13953, Country: 699, Name: "OZ", codeProduct: 12 }],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.Code]) {
        this[a.Code] = { Code: a.Code, Country: a.Country, Name: a.Name, codeProduct: a.codeProduct };
        grouped.push(this[a.Code]);
        return;
    }
    this[a.Code].codeProduct += ', ' + a.codeProduct;
}, Object.create(null));
console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try my best to answer this without fully understanding what you're attempting to do...

So you have your duplicate values in `prodArray`, great. Now you want them to be placed *back* into the array you just removed them from? Sure. To append an element to the end of an array, you use the [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method.

I'm assuming the thing that you're caught up on is grabbing those missing JSON properties, `Country` and `Name`, and adding them back to the elements in `prodArray`.  But since we know that `Code` is the same, we can use that to find the "missing" values. So here's how I'd do it, assuming `a` is your original array:

```
for (var i in prodArray) {

    // find the duplicate in the orginal array
    for (var j in a) {

        if (a[j].Code == prodArray[i].Code) {

            // found it, now append into a
            a.push(a[j]);
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

Am I close?

Comment: Thank you Danny for your answere, sorry if I won`t be clear.